# Building intuition for the étale topology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, grothendieck-topology, etale-covers

My Honours supervisors have charged me with building intuition for étale morphisms and the étale topology. Their suggestions were to "compute the étale topology in a few simple cases", such as $\mathbb{A}^1_k$, $\mathbb{P}^1_k$, $Spec(k)$ etc. I have worked out a few examples but nothing on the scale they suggested; from what I've seen, it seems like the étale topology should depend on the characteristic and perhaps some other factors as well. It doesn't seem like I can describe every étale open set in general.

Does anyone know of a source where I could read more about the above? I was envisaging calculating a "basis" for the étale topology on these example schemes.

Alternatively, does anyone have any other suggestions for building intuition for étale morphisms and the étale topology? I am looking for a few concrete examples to keep in mind.